# Swift 2.1 - Pre-populating some data only once at first run (Core Data)

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9

I have a small subset of data that needs to be pre-populated at the first time user launches the app. I've looked at other options like bundling an app with existing sqlite files or csv/json but since the data that needs to be preloaded are only 4 records of one data model like 
`var categories = [category1, category2, category3, category4]`, I feel it would be more efficient if I hardcode this.

But how I can make sure this insert call is only executed once at the first runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I preload data for my app and I handle this one of two ways:

- Set a bit in `NSUserDefaults` that you have done the import, and then check for that at startup (this can also be expanded to allow for easy updating of files on a new version, for instance).
- Fetch the number of objects for a given Entity, if > 0 do nothing (as already imported).

Comment: Thanks. I've set up Category entity using Core Data and I'm allowing users to add their own categories along with the default 4 so I'm looking for Core Data use case if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a search for an Entity, and if that entity returns 0 results, you could populate it with the initial info.

```
var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
let dataFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Data")

var result:[MyData]?
do {
    result = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(dataFetch) as? [MyData]
} catch {
    print("Error fetching data")
}

if let data = result {
    if data.count == 0 {
        //create your data and save it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would you place this block of code? I don't know if I want to make this part of create/update function as I want to avoid checking this every time user executes create/update.

Answer (score 0):

This is presumably coming very late and you've likely already fixed it, but I had this problem a little while ago.

You could set up something like the following in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let isPreloaded = defaults.bool(forKey: "isPreloaded")
    if !isPreloaded {
        preloadData()
        defaults.set(true, forKey: "isPreloaded")
    }

    return true
}
```

This way, your app would check every time if it had already preloaded the data, and if it had, it would skip it. This is assuming that you've already got a preloadData function of some sort set up.